# Lagrange-Charpit equations in vector form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

As we know if $x(t),y(t)\in \mathbb{R}$, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
   \frac{dx}{dt} &= a(x,y)\\
   \frac{dy}{dt} &= b(x,y)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}admits the Lagrange-Charpit equations $$\frac{dx}{a(x,y)}=\frac{dy}{b(x,y)},$$ with $a$, $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

My question is if $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$, which imply $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$, then what is the form of Lagrange-Charpit equations?

I hope my question is reasonable. Can anyone please provide me some comments or lecture notes?

Thanks

Comment: Could you connect your formulation back to a first order (linear) PDE? What is then the distinction between components labeled $x$ and those labeled $y$? $\dot x_i(s)=a_i(x(s))$ transforms to $ds=\frac{dx_i}{a_i(x)}$.